# phpunit abstract class constant

Tags: class, phpunit, constants, abstract

I'm trying to find a way to test a abstract class constant that must exist and match/not match a value. Example:

```
// to be extended by ExternalSDKClild
abstract class ExternalSDK {
    const VERSION = '3.1.1.'; 
}


class foo extends AController {
    public function init() {   
        if ( ExternalSDK::VERSION !== '3.1.1' ) {
            throw new Exception('Wrong ExternalSDK version!');
        }

        $this->setExternalSDKChild(new ExternalSDKChild());
    }
}
```

Limitations... The framework we use doesn't allow dependency injection in the init() method. (Suggestion to refactor the init() method could be the way to go...)

The unit tests and code coverage I have run, cover all but the Exception. I can't figure out a way to make the ExternalSDK::Version to be different from what it is.

All thoughts welcome

Answer (score 1):

First, refactor the call to `new` into a separate method.

Second, add a method to acquire the version instead of accessing the constant directly. Class constants in PHP are compiled into the file when parsed and cannot be changed.* Since they are accessed statically, there's no way to override it without swapping in a different class declaration with the same name. The only way to do that using standard PHP is to run the test in a separate process which is very expensive.

```
class ExternalSDK {
    const VERSION = '3.1.1';

    public function getVersion() {
        return static::VERSION;
    }
}

class foo extends AController {
    public function init() {
        $sdk = $this->createSDK();
        if ( $sdk->getVersion() !== '3.1.1' ) {
            throw new Exception('Wrong ExternalSDK version!');
        }

        $this->setExternalSDKChild($sdk);
    }

    public function createSDK() {
        return new ExternalSDKChild();
    }
}
```

And now for the unit test.

```
class NewerSDK extends ExternalSDK {
    const VERSION = '3.1.2';
}

/**
 * @expectedException Exception
 */
function testInitFailsWhenVersionIsDifferent() {
    $sdk = new NewerSDK();
    $foo = $this->getMock('foo', array('createSDK'));
    $foo->expects($this->once())
        ->method('createSDK')
        ->will($this->returnValue($sdk));
    $foo->init();
}
```

*[Runkit](http://php.net/manual/en/book.runkit.php) provides [`runkit_constant_redefine()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.runkit-constant-redefine.php) which may work here. You'll need to catch the exception manually instead of using `@expectedException` so you can reset the constant back to the correct value. Or you can do it in `tearDown()`.

```
function testInitFailsWhenVersionIsDifferent() {
    try {
        runkit_constant_redefine('ExternalSDK::VERSION', '3.1.0');
        $foo = new foo();
        $foo->init();
        $failed = true;
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
        $failed = false;
    }
    runkit_constant_redefine('ExternalSDK::VERSION', '3.1.1');
    if ($failed) {
        self::fail('Failed to detect incorrect SDK version.');
    }
}
```

Comment: Having a getter for a class constant entirely undermines the purpose of a constant IMHO

Comment: @donatJ - You can refactor this easily by removing the constant and return the value directly from `getVersion`, but it was easier to demonstrate this unit-testing technique with a smaller change.